# I can not run service in android background

Tags: android, notifications, background, intentservice

I am running service in android background, and I have some problem.
Over Android Oreo version, I tried to run endless service using AlarmService and `StartForegroundService()` in android.
but I have got no result.

My testing device is Xiaomi, YunOS, Huawei and android version is 9.0, 4.4 and YunOS 5.1
At first, when mainactivity run and next close, in `onResume()` and `onPause()` function, I started service with `startforegroundservice()` and `startservice()` function using Receiver.
There are some codes with the followings:

```
- MainActivity

public void onResume() {
    mContext.stopService(new Intent(mContext, AppService.class));
}

public void onPause() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, RestartReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction("ACTION_REBOOT");
    mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
}

-RestartReceiver

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    {
        context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, 
        AppForegroundService.class));
    } else {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, AppService.class));
    }
}

- AppForegroundService



     @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            ToastUtil.showToast(this, "AppForegroundService onStartCommand");
            Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand");
            startForeground(startId, getStartNotification());
            startService(new Intent(this, AppService.class));
            stopSelf();
            return START_STICKY;
        }

- AppService

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    RestartAlarm();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: service done");
    ToastUtil.showToast(this, "onDestroy: service done");
}
private void RestartAlarm()
{
    ToastUtil.showToast(this, "Start AlarmService");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RestartReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction("ACTION_RESTART");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, 
    intent, 0);
    long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    Log.d(TAG, "RestartAlarm: " + firstTime);
    firstTime += 1000;

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) 
    getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 
    firstTime, 1000, pendingIntent);
}

- Manifest.xml

<service
    android:name=".service.AppService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:stopWithTask="false"/>
<service android:name=".service.AppForegroundService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"/>
<receiver
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:name=".service.AutoStartReceiver"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="ACTION_REBOOT" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" 
        android:priority="999"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver
    android:name=".service.RestartReceiver"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="ACTION_RESTART"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" 
/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" 
/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
    android:required="false" />
<!-- 网络 -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" 
/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" 
/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<!-- added from 2.7.2 -->
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.INSTANT_APP_FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER" 
/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do nothing about that some device manufacturers doesn't allow services to run in background when app is closed it's the os which kills the service however you need to give your app self start permission if it's really necessary for you to run service in background!

Comment: Thank you for your respond, I really appreciate it, but I have one thing to ask.What means self start? it means autostart?

Comment: Yes exactly giving autostart permission is a temporary workaround for this problem however that permission will be needed to be granted from user side!

Comment: programmatically, is it impossible to give autostart permission?
i mean, I would like to give autostart permission automatically, after install package .

Comment: No autostart permission cannot be granted programmatically i would always require user interaction atleast once in your application context however on start of app you can show a dialog to user asking for auto start permission and after permission is granted you can resume your application!

Comment: Please mark my answer correct if it helped i'll appreciate it! :)

Comment: Thank you for your answering, one more question, and the dialogue you mention is system dialog or customized dialog? if it is system dialog, How to show a dialog to user asking for auto start permission?

Comment: It'll be a custom dialog created by you in your app place a button in your custom dialog and on click of it redirect user to give auto start permission!

Comment: Really appreciate it, how to redirect? I am new programmer in android, I am sorry to ask many question.

Comment: Thank you very much, really helpful! A++++++++++++++++++++++

Comment: Glad It helped :)