# How do I keep media player service running until it's killed?

Tags: android, android-service

I have a media player service that gets killed everytime the user clears recent apps. I want the service to continue playing on the background. I have tried

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(@Nullable Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

and

```
mediaPlayer.setWakeMode(context, PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
```

but it's not working. How do I solve this?

Comment: Take a look at my answer in this question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57966822/i-can-not-run-service-in-android-background/57966938#57966938

Comment: try foreground service

Comment: @MirianaItani Thanks! This actually works

Comment: @sammyukavi I am going to add it as an answer with an example to make sure everything is clear and so that other can benefit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google did some updates:

Some of those updates included security and it reached the services. This means that we can no longer perform lengthy operations in the background without notifying the user.

> Foreground
>   A foreground service performs some operation that is noticeable to the
>   user. For example, an audio app would use a foreground service to play
>   an audio track. Foreground services must display a Notification.
>   Foreground services continue running even when the user isn't
>   interacting with the app.
>
> Background
>   A background service performs an operation that isn't directly noticed
>   by the user. For example, if an app used a service to compact its
>   storage, that would usually be a background service. Note: If your app
>   targets API level 26 or higher, the system imposes restrictions on
>   running background services when the app itself isn't in the
>   foreground. In most cases like this, your app should use a scheduled
>   job instead.

Make sure to call **startForeground** as soon as possible

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");
    createNotificationChannel();
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0, notificationIntent, 0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Foreground Service")
            .setContentText(input)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();

    startForeground(1, notification);

    //do heavy work on a background thread


    //stopSelf();

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

This is how you start the foreground service:

```
 public void startService() {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
    serviceIntent.putExtra("inputExtra", "Foreground Service Example in Android");

    ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, serviceIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As specified in Mr.Patel answer,

Many of the manufactures wont allow running of background service when frontend Activity is not running or removed from the recent list.

There is a way of achiving your requirement.

You can run your service in the background by setting a non cancellable notification from your application. Till you close your notification forcefully programatically using a close button, your service will be running in the background.

Hope this will solve your problem.